# Windows 10 - Enter PIN Screen No Done Button

Tags: insider-preview, pin

Just downloaded Windows 10 on my Lumia 925, can't get past enter pin screen. There is no done button and when I type the pin nothing happens.

Comment: What build are you on? There was a known bug like this in 10124, but was supposed to be fixed in 10166.

Answer (score 2):

Tap the screen to the right of the "Enter PIN" notice / masked PIN numbers. Seems the "OK" button is invisible :b